# How I get data from fun onResult to fun onMapReady in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android-mvp

I use retrofit for get data From API. i will displays data ini the maps. data was successfull get from retrofit, but i found problem get data response to fun onMapReady. i don't know to be it

```
class HomeMapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback,
MapHomeContract.View {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
 lateinit var presenter: MapHomePresenter
 lateinit var prefsManager: PrefsManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_maps)
    supportActionBar!!.title = "Posisi driver"
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    prefsManager = PrefsManager(this)
    presenter = MapHomePresenter(this)
    presenter.getAnak(prefsManager.prefsIdUser)

}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap


    for (dataAnak in anak) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}


override fun onResult(dataAnakResponse: AnakResponse) {
    dataAnakResponse.anak
}
```

}

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onMapReady() is called when you initially start the Map Activity.  You can set the map data in onResult.

```
override fun onResult(dataAnakResponse: AnakResponse) {
   val anak =  dataAnakResponse.anak

for (dataAnak in anak) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```